# About size property in KeyPoint of SIFT features

Tags: size, sift

when I use SIFT in OpenCV, I find the size of each keypoints are different, even the points are belong to the same octave / layer. From my understanding regarding SIFT, the size refers to the radius or diameter used to circle a neighborhood area to calculate the main angle. It is usually related to the scale of current key point. So if two key points belong to same scale, why the sizes are different?
Maybe something miss understanding here.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the code that calculates the key-points size:
The method is adjustLocalExtrema():
kpt.size = sigma*powf(2.f, (layer + xi) / nOctaveLayers)*(1 << octv)*2;

Both the layer and the octave are the same for all the keypoints on the same layer/octave , yet the xi differs. It is related to the hessian matrix decomposition.

Comment: could you also comment shortly on what xi is?